# Calling functions in the parent and transferring data to the child

Tags: reactjs

I have two components, `Layout` and `Chat`. `Chat is a child`. When I call the function `showChat()`, I have a message in the `Chat` component: `Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`. I am trying to transfer data from parent to child.

**Layout**

```
import Chat from '../components/Chat';


const Layout = ({children, match, history}) => {

  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    visibleChat: false,
    chatters: []
    });

  const getAllChatters = () => {

    axios({
      method: 'GET',
      url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API}/get-all-chatters`
    })
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res, 'chatters');

      setValues({...values, chatters: res.data});
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('error', err && err.response ? err.response.data  : '');

    })
  }


  
  const showChat = () => {
    setValues({visibleChat: !visibleChat});
    getAllChatters();
  };

  
    const {visibleChat, chatters} = values;


    const nav = () => (   
        <Menu>     
          <Menu.Item>
            <MessageOutlined onClick={showChat}/>
          </Menu.Item>        
        </Menu>
    );
    
    return (
        <Fragment>
            {nav()}
            <Chat visibleChat = {visibleChat} visibleChatUser = {visibleChatUser} chatters = {chatters} idSender = {_id} roleSender = {role} onCloseChat = {onCloseChat}/>
        </Fragment>
    );
};
```

**Chat**

```
const Chat = ({visibleChat, chatters}) => {

  const [values, setValues] = useState({

  });
  

  return (
    <>
        <Drawer
          title="Drawer"
          onClose={onCloseChat}
          visible={visibleChat}
        >
          <ul className="chatters">
                {chatters.map(function(chatter) {
                return <li className="chatter" key={chatter['_id']}>
                        </li>;
                })}
          </ul>
        </Drawer>
    </>
  );
};

export default Chat;
```

Comment: you forgot to merge the old state with the new state inside the `showChat` function - you are overwriting the existing state. You probably meant to do:  `setValues({ ...values, visibleChat: !visibleChat });`

Comment: Tip: As the value of `visibleChat` is updated based on its previous value, use the functional form of state setter function: `setValues(currentState => ({ ...currentState, visibleChat: currentState.visibleChat }))`